# Update several chart series name

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to update a series name in a chart legend with VBA. I have tried 2 ways and both work. But a problem occurs when I try to select or modify data with click mode in my presentation.

1.

```
.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Name 1"
.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Name 2"
```

When I click to modify data, legend is automatically changed by `Serie1` and `Serie2`. This doesn't happen when only one serie is set with VBA (i.e. one line is commented out).

2.

```
.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "Name 1"
.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C1").Value = "Name 2"
```

This time, I can't open Excel data window. Nothing happens (no errors or messages but wait cursor briefly appear).

Comment: What is the qualification for the dot notation?  i would assume you have workbook.worksheet.shapes.chart... which means that your re-use of workbook.worsheet is an issue

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a with block `With MySlide.Shapes.Item("CHT_1")`. Is it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your full answer, but may help with understanding the request.

lea, your with block seems correct for working within PPT, though your use of Excel has... some issues.  From what you're writing, there is a signfiicant breakdown:

```
.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "Name 1"
```

My assumption is that you want Excel range B1 to be the name for Series 1, and C1 to be Series 2.  I believe you want to work with the series collection:

```
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = fpath & "\" & "[WorkbookName.xlsx]Sheet1!B1"
.SeriesCollection(2).Name = fpath & "\" & "[WorkbookName.xlsx]Sheet1!C1"
```

Where fpath is the folder path for the workbook.

I would wonder why you're not getting an error on #2 (or are you?  if so, please state the error code), unless you have On Error Resume Next in your code, or some other type of error handling.

---

**Edit1:**

Fixing the Excel file to overwrite a value based on the series name of the chart Series name (assumes Excel file is open, otherwise open it):

```
Workbooks("NAme").Sheets("Name").Range("B1").Value = .SeriesCollection(1).Name
Workbooks("NAme").Sheets("Name").Range("C1").Value = .SeriesCollection(2).Name
```

Regarding selecting/modifying the source data using the Presentation, can you please post your related code for generation of the series data into your post?  Depending on how it is being generated may be an issue (e.g., if you use "new series (1)" twice, that could be a problem, etc.).

Comment: I don't want to use the value of B1 and C1 cells. I was trying to rewrite them because it seems to be these headers used as series names. My chart data are not coming from an excel file. It's an embedded chart in powerpoint. I don't have any error when running both scenarii. Tell me if something is unclear.

Comment: @lea you're trying to overwrite Excel cell values with the names of the series?  I'll fix that code to go in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (just add a barchart in a presentation pptm) :

```
Sub main()

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("CHT").chart
    .ChartData.Workbook.worksheets(1).Range("B4") = 999
    .ChartData.Workbook.worksheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "Name 1"
    .ChartData.Workbook.worksheets(1).Range("C1").Value = "Name 2"
End With

ActivePresentation.Save

End Sub
```

After that if you try to click to select data, it doesn't work (just waiting cursor). 
Not sure (maybe i'm just doing something the wrong way, that's the point), but it looks like a bug to me because i tried to run it again and had an error message "Method workbook object chartdata failed"... Chartdata window seems to be unavailable.